# Create a table with mysqli prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli

`I have the simple this very simple code below:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `alerte`";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nom_alerte'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id_priorite'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    }

}
```

I would like to use a prepared statement but I am not sure how.

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * 
                                FROM `alerte`
                                WHERE `id_alerte` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_membre);                             
$stmt->execute(); 

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nom_alerte'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id_priorite'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

solution, thanks for the comment! :

```
    $id_alerte = '5';
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT  `nom_alerte`, 
                                `id_priorite`
                            FROM `alerte`
                            WHERE `id_alerte` < ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_alerte);                             
$stmt->execute(); 

$stmt->bind_result($nom_alerte, $date_debut_alerte, $date_fin_alerte,      $description_alerte, $status, $id_equipe, $id_priorite);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $nom_alerte . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $id_priorite . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: don't use *,pass field_name in select query and also in bind_param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, if `mysqlnd` is installed on your system, you could use `->get_result()` method

Or use `->bind_result()` if not available to fetch your results from the prepared statement:

`->get_result()` version:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `alerte` WHERE `id_alerte` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_membre);                             
$stmt->execute(); 

$results = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nom_alerte'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id_priorite'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Or the `bind_result()` version:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nom_alerte`, `id_priorite` FROM `alerte` WHERE `id_alerte` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_membre);                             
$stmt->execute(); 

$stmt->bind_result($nom_alerte, $id_priorite);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $nom_alerte . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $id_priorite . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```